# org table and named columns for babel processing

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Data in an org table can be processed (row-by-row) in src blocks like so:

```
#+NAME: test-table
| a | b |
|---+---|
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

#+NAME: test-table-script
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var table=test-table
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (cadr x)) table)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test-table-script
| 2 | 4 |
```

In the example above, though, the table is only available through the `table` variable, and I have to pull the elements in each row/column out manually.

In the case that the original table has column names (as in the case above) is there a way to have the values columns of the table automatically bound to those variables (`a` and `b` in the example table) in a `BEGIN_SRC` block?

Comment: That is an interesting question, to which unfortunately I don't know the answer. If you don't get an answer here, maybe you can ask it on the ML.

Comment: worst-comes-to-worst I can just use a `mapcar` and a `cl-destructuring-bind`, and yep, the ML might be a good option as well

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses `org-babel-get-colnames` and `cl-destructuring-bind`. Note that the table colnames are strings and need to be interned. The example shows the original data with an additional column.

```
#+NAME: test-table-script
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var table=test-table :colnames no
  (require 'cl)
  (defmacro with-table (table expression)
    "Given an org table with colnames, evaluate an expression using the colnames.
Note: use ':colnames no' in the header -- this imports the colnames 
but does not export them."
    `(let* ((table-with-colnames (org-babel-get-colnames ,table))
        (names (loop for name in (cdr table-with-colnames)
             collect (if (stringp name) (intern name) name))))
       (funcall
    `(lambda (data)
           (mapcar (lambda (row)
                 (cl-destructuring-bind ,names row ,',expression))
               data))
    (car table-with-colnames))))

  ;; example to add a third column
  (cons '(a b c) (cons 'hline (with-table table (list a b (+ a b)))))
#+END_SRC
```

With output:

```
#+RESULTS: test-table-script
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 |
```

This approach could be readily extended to transform columns, either replacing values or adding a new column. The macro could also be improved through the addition of some gensym's.